# C FastCGI программа для HTTP/2

Tags: c, fastcgi, http2, lighttpd

Нашёл в интернете [Hello World](https://github.com/jerryvig/lighttpd-fastcgi-c/blob/master/hello_fastcgi.c). Как сделать то же самое, но с использованием сообщений протокола HTTP/2? Должна ли меняться структура программы, или это всё сугубо настройки сервера?

Comment: Исходя из общих соображений, CGI скрипты должны работать. В HTTP/2 поменяли протокольную часть, но оставили структуру сообщения. Поэтому CGI скрипт получит те же данные запроса, а его вывод будет отправлен сервером клиенту. Единственное, push функционал нельзя реализовать на существующими средствами.

Comment: Учитывая что push не взлетел и его выпиливают, это небольшое ограничение